# Padding not shrinking when zooming out below 80% in Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, css

I have been banging my head on the table trying to figure out why this happens. I have set up an anchor that has padding on the top, bottom, and left sides. Inside that anchor is two text elements and as the background of the anchor is an image.

Now when I zoom out (not shrinking the viewport) in chrome, everything seems to shrink as expected until I hit 80%. At this point the content continues to shrink but not the padding on the left side! In FireFox it seems to work as expected.

Attached is my code, please any ideas on how to explain this will be appreciated.

```css
html {font-family: 'tex gyre heros', helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 10px}

a,a:link,a:visited,a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: inherit;}

.logo {
    padding: 10em 10em 0 0;
    background: url(../images/some-image.svg) left center no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.logo.main {
    padding: 1.2em 0 2.1em 12em;
}
.logo.main .logotype, .logotype.block {
    display: block;
}
.logotype {
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.logotype.title {
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: #646469;
}
.logotype.subtitle {
    padding: 0 0 0 0.078em;
    font-size: 2.1em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Company">
        <base href="">
        <title>Company</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a class="logo main" href="">
                <span class="logotype title">Line 1</span>
                <span class="logotype subtitle">Line 2</span>
            </a>
        </header>
        <section>
        </section>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I ask, what is the idea behind zooming-out your page and what is the desired effect that you are striving for? Scaling the browser's zoom capabilities and resizing the viewport are two very different things.

Comment: I am aware browser zoom and the resizing of the viewport are two different things. This is strictly a browser zoom issue. To see my desired effect, you can throw this into FireFox and see how it zooms out vs in Chrome. What you will see is everything scales proportionately in FireFox but not Chrome. Honestly there is no functional reason to solve this, I am simply trying to figure out this discrepancy and how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here comes from the difference in pixel representation between browsers. Meaning - Chrome and Firefox might handle some fixed pixel values differently (don't ask me why, its just how the world functions with everything).

> **Possible solution 1:** Try and set the padding values in **%** so that they can be relative to each other.
>
> **Possible solution 2:** This thread on **[CSS Tricks about not breaking the layout when zooming](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/please-help-how-to-allow-zoom-without-affecting-layout/)**:
>
> **Possible solution 3**: Check your viewport tags. **[Use this thread.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)**

Like @DarkxPunk said, the link goes to the far left side on Firefox and somehow does not go to the far left in Chrome.

Issue visualization for further investigation:

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Firefox:**

[image]

Comment: Sadly percentages don't solve the problem, all it does is seem to tie the padding to the width of the page... I can't figure out a way to limit that. Even on top of that it does not cause the zooming to do anything new when you zoom out.

Comment: @DarkxPunk , try and go trough this thread here - https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/please-help-how-to-allow-zoom-without-affecting-layout/

Comment: This might be due to some bad CSS or document meta settings. I have also updated my answer, look up and read solution 2 and 3, I hope this helps.

Comment: Ive read through and played as much as possible and got to the same conclusion as the guy in that thread. The solution wasn't a solution because no horizontal scroll bars... Meaning it scaled, but it was still being affected by the viewport. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm. Another thing that you can try is to set base for `rem` or `em` in pixels - meaning, you should set `body { font-size: 10px; }` which will be that base I referred to - e.g. `1rem` = `10px`. Then simply set all your relative paddings and margins in either `em` or `rem` , that way it will depend on the font-size, which scrolls proportionally in all browsers (I hope..)

Comment: I am confused by your suggestion... My HTML is already set to 10px (I set it to body it makes no difference), and my padding is already using em, but fine I change it to rem (even though its inherent to the html since there is no font size specified above the logo) and still no change... It may possibly be a rounding issue as outlined before by webkit but there must be a way to circumvent it.